# Secrets Within A Book

Tags: visual, steganography

After a hard day of work, you return home and open your mailbox.  All is usual, but you soon find another letter with an unknown sender.  You carefully open the letter to keep the contents as it is.  The message reads:

> Dear Receiver,
>
> When you have received this letter, go to the library.  If you search hard enough, it will lead you to the answer.  Enter through the back door.  Make sure to enter quietly, careful not to wake the (unexpectedly sleeping) guard dogs.  Once you have found the book we are looking for, tiptoe to the side exit.  Give us the book you have found and have in your hands to receive your reward.
>
> **PS:** Lemons are sour treats. ~~~ Water on rock/dirt.
>
> ~Unknown

The letter comes with an image, which you assume is unrelated to the message.  Somehow, you think it could play a big role later on.  The image is attached below:

> [image]

As read in the letter, **what is the *"genre"* of the book you are looking for?**

Personally, I would start decoding the letter.

Comment: My first question!  Hope its not to easy or hard.  I would like any recommendations for later puzzles.

Comment: More like this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PS of the letter's

> first letters are **Last words**.

That's a clue to the rest of the note.  So we take the

> last word of each sentence: library answer door dogs exit reward.
>
>  The first letters of those words spell: **Ladder**

So we should focus on

> the ladder in the picture rather than the other parts.

And

> the letters on the ladder can be rearranged to make "Acronym MYS" so maybe we're looking for a **Mystery** book.

The letters on the steps

> can be rearranged to spell **wrong**, so don't pursue that direction.

The letters near the climber

> can be rearranged to spell **incorrect**, so don't pursue that direction either.

Comment: Yes! You are correct!  Could you provide some feedback for later problems?  Or was it a little bit easy?

Comment: @Acerfire37 I just happened to be working on a similar puzzle a couple days ago so went straight to the idea of first letters. I think too many people try to make their puzzles too hard.  I'd focus instead on making them fun!

Comment: @Acerfire37 The only thing I might've tweaked would be to not add the "wrong" and "incorrect" anagrams.  With them, you had two different ways of pointing to the ladder.  If, instead, the other two parts of the picture were just jumbled letters, then you'd *have* to solve the note before you realized the ladder was the only important part.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Yeah, I realized it afterwards that I should have jumbled the letters, but since I already had posted it, it was sort of too late.   Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Acerfire37 Or you could've put red herrings in by having other genres on the climber and the steps.